# Updating Parse object in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am creating an application that has Parse cloud integration.
Somewhere in my code, I intend to edit an existing Parse object (of class "Group") and update it on the cloud.

I am using the following code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"someID" block:^(PFObject *group, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            [group addObject:@"someString" forKey:@"members"];
            [group saveInBackground];
        }
    }];
```

members is an array in my Group class and I want to add strings to this array. However, when I run this I get this error:  Error: A Group with this name already exists. (Code: 142, Version: 1.4.2)

I tried adding the following line right before adding the string to the array:

```
group[@"name"] = @"differentName";
```

and it worked! Which I find pretty weird. I don't want to change my group's name, I just want to update my array and save it to the database..

What's the solution to this, any help will be appreciated please!

Thank you

This is where I set up the group's properties and save it:

```
PFObject *group = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Group"];
group[@"name"] = self.groupName.text;
group[@"description"] = self.groupDescription.text;
[group saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // The object has been saved.
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
 }];
```

Comment: This sounds like an error from a Cloud Code function. Do you have a beforeSave set up for the Group class? If yes, post the code here please.

Comment: Good, but my question was: do you have any Cloud Code set up that runs on each save of a Group object and checks if a group already exists?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but doesn't Parse automatically check if a group already exists before creating a duplicate? but in any case, no I don't have a Cloud Code set up. @BjörnKaiser

Comment: No it wouldn't automatically check for duplicates in custom classes, the only places where this would be done, is for the standard classes `Roles` and  `User` (where it would check if a username/email is already taken). But for custom classes this should not be true to my knowledge. But if you're not using Cloud Code this sounds like a bug, update your Parse iOS SDK (v1.6.4 is the current version atm), try to repro and if it still doesn't work after updating the SDK, file a bug at https://parse.com/help and comment with the link to the report here and I'll look into it.

Comment: Ok I updated the SDK and the issue wasn't solved. I filed a bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/730981790332460/ @BjörnKaiser

Comment: I honestly have no experience in JavaScript. I tried following the Cloud Code guide on Parse.com but I can't find documentation for the request.object.isNew and how to solve my issue.
Could you provide me with a quick solution to this please? @BjörnKaiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my reply on the bug report, the issue is a *beforeSave* function that checks if a group with name *XYZ* already exists. As a *beforeSave* function gets triggered on each save, not only on creation, all subsequent saves to this object will fail.

To work around this, you should check if this is a save triggered due to object creation vs. due to updating an existing object. To do this, you can use a convenience function, `isNew` of the object to check what triggered the save. Behind the scenes this actually just checks if the object that is being saved already has an `objectId` set or not.

Here is some sample code that should fix your issue:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Group", function(request, response) {
   var object = request.object;

   // If it is a new object, check if a Group with that name already exists
   if (object.isNew()) {
       var Group = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
       var query = new Parse.Query(Group);
       query.equalTo("name", object.get("name"));
       query.find({
           success: function(results) {
               if (results.length == 0) {
                   // There is no group with that name, so we can save
                   response.success();
               } else {
                   response.error("A group with this name already exists");
               }
           },
           error: function(error) {
               response.error(error.message);
           }
       });
   } else {
       // This is just an update, so lets save it
       response.success();
   }
});
```

This code should do the trick, however, it does not check for an already existing `Group` when someone simply updates an existing group, that's something I will leave to you to implement. You could do this in the query itself, so you always check if there is a group with that name, and if yes, check if the already existing group's `objectId` matches the one that you are currently saving, if it does you can safely return a success, otherwise return an error.

Comment: Great that worked for me! I used the terminal and wrote "parse deploy" after adding your clode to mycloudcode directory. The group was updated successfully. Thanks!
Do you recommend any guides to help me figure out how to use Cloud Code? Parse documentation doesn't help a lot